# Export Google chart as image

Tags: angularjs, google-visualization

I am using angular-google-chart to draw chart.I need to export chart as (.png/ .jpg) type image .I am trying to export a chart on button click event..

How could i export chart as (.png/ .jpg) image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use getImageURI() to get a static PNG version of a chart - the Printing example at the Google Chart site details how to invoke getImageURI(), and then its just a case of executing this in your onclick event. https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/printing